# iOS dev - sharing screen captures

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, drawing

I'm looking to write an app that lets users draw a game, something like tic-tac-toe, for example. One user would begin by drawing the grid, and then each player could literally draw their own O or X. It would be a multiplayer game where each user has his/her own device.

I'm not sure what would be the best way to share this data from device to device. I've only been able to think of 2 options:

1. Should I attempt to upload a screenshot to the server after each player makes a move?
2. Should I upload the exact points where the user is drawing and then redraw these points on the other user's screen?

Any other suggestions, or maybe a point in the right direction? I'm fairly new to all of this so please don't be too harsh ;)

Comment: Your second point sounds like the best option. If you do incremental images it's likely to involve transferring much more data, and also you may have different displays on the two devices (e.g. one with Retina display and the other without)

Comment: Good point - didn't even think about the Retina display issue. I assuming the work flow for the second option would be something like:
- Player 1 uploads data points
- Player 2 continuously checking for new points

... and so on

Answer (score 2):

starting out on a multiplayer game (even if it is a straightforward one) is ambitious :) if you don't mind restricting yourself to iOS5 and above, then i would check out the new turn based multiplayer game functionality. there's a good tutorial here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1

Comment: Wow looks like a great API, I'll definitely need to read into it. Great find - thanks a lot